# Javafx open another fxml in the another window with button

Tags: javafx, window, fxml, stage

Is it possible in javafx to open new stages (windows) from another fxml with a button?
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yes. Can you show some code and explain which part you are stuck with?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the code below on button click:

```
try {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("ABC");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works this code, but I'd like a window can be moved separately and close top right corner.

Comment: To move and close window comment line with style: StageStyle.UNDECORATED

Comment: It's also a good idea to add `stage.onCloseRequestProperty().setValue(e -> Platform.exit());` to the starting window's stage in order to exit the application closing all the other windows on pressing it's close button.

Answer (score 25):

I had to modify the code a bit and it works fine.
Thank you again for the code!

```
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {               
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/A.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```